# jmeter and apachetop - why I see different values?

Tags: apache, jmeter

Probably explanation is simple - but I couldn't find answer to my question:

I am running jmeter test from one VM (worker) to another (target). On worker I have jmeter with 100 threads (100 users). On target I have API that runs on Apache. When I run "apachetop -f access_log" on target, I see only about 7 req/s. 
Can someone explain me, why I don't see 100 req/s on target?

In test result in jmeter I see always 200 OK, so all request are hitting the target, and moreover target always responds. So I am not dropping any requests here. Network bandwidth between machines is 1G. What I am missing here?

Thanks,
Daddy

Comment: and what do you see in JMeter for average and throughput (e.g. use Summary Report)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100 users doesn't necessarily mean 100 requests per second, even more, it is highly unlikely.

According to [JMeter glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html):

> **Elapsed time.** JMeter measures the elapsed time from just before sending the request to just after the last response has been received. JMeter does not include the time needed to render the response, nor does JMeter process any client code, for example Javascript.

Roughly, if JMeter is able to get response from server in 1 second - you will get 100 requests/second. If response time will be 2 seconds - throughput will be 50 requests/second, etc, response time 4 seconds - 25 requests/second, etc.

Also JMeter configuration matters. If you don't provide enough loops you may run into a situation where some threads already finished and some are not even started. See [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected) article for more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks guys! Actually, you were both right. 100 users in JMeter doesn't mean 100 requests per second on target. In my case it was something about 7 req/sec because of slow response from target (average 13 secs). Everything becomes clear after enabling Summary Report (and some listener to see reponse times on graph).

Answer (score 1):

```
Your target load = 100 threads ( you are assuming it should generate 100 req/sec as per your plan)
Your actual load = 7 req / sec = 7*3600 / hour = 25200
Per thread throughput = 25200 / 100 threads = 252 iterations / thread / hour
Per transaction time = 3600 / 252 = 14.2 secs
```

This means, JMeter should be actually sending each request every 14 secs per thread. i.e., 100 requests for every 14.2 secs.

Now, analyze your JMeter summary report for the transaction timers to find out where the remaining 13.2 secs are being spent.

Possible issues are
1. High DNS resolution time (DNS issue)
2. High connection setup time (indicates load balancer issues)
3. High Request send time (indicates n/w or firewall throttling issues)
4. High request receive time (same as #3)

Now, the time that you see in Apache logs are mostly visible to JMeter as time to first byte time. I am not sure about the machine that you are running your testing. If your worker can support curl, use Curl to find the components for a single request.

```
echo 'request payload for POST'  
| curl -X POST -H 'User-Agent: myBrowser' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @- -s -w '\nDNS time:\t%{time_namelookup}\nTCP Connect time:\t%{time_connect}\nAppCon Protocol time:\t%{time_appconnect}\nRedirect time:\t%{time_redirect}\nPreXfer time:\t%{time_pretransfer}\nStartXfer time:\t%{time_starttransfer}\n\nTotal time:\t%{time_total}\n' http://mytest.test.com
```

If the above output indicates no such issues then the time must have been spent within JMeter. You should tune your JMeter implementation by using various options like beanshell / JSR223 etc.